# Append 3 Range of List in a List of List (Matrix) - Pyhton3

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, matrix, range

I have the next code in Python where i can print a pattern of a diamond in 0 and 1, for some purposes, i want to store my printing diamond in a matrix or list of lists, i'm a beginner in python.

```
    length = 3

    for x in list(range(length)) + list(reversed(range(length - 1))) + list(reversed(range(0))):
        print('{:0<{w1}}{:1>{w2}}{:0>{w3}}'.format('', '', '', w1=length - x - 1, w2=x * 2 + 1, w3=length - x - 1))
```

My result is a diamond like this:

```
00100
01110
11111
01110
00100
```

How can i store my printing diamond in a matrix or list of lists ?.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How can i store my printing diamond in a matrix or list of lists ?.

Comment: Just append it to a list instead of printing it.

Comment: for example? i am a beginner on python,